# Hide all the same elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide

I wish know how to hide all the same elements using jQuery, I tryied the following code but that just worked for the first element of the same kind.

```
$('#duracion').hide();
$('#video-box img').on({
mouseenter: function() {
    $('#duracion').slideDown(200);
},

mouseleave: function() {
    $('#duracion').slideUp(200);
}
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean there is more than one `#duracion` element? You can't do that. Elements' id attributes are unique.

Comment: @Blender but `#duracion` is an ID - having more than one of those is poor webiquette. I think what he needs to do it `$('HTMLtag').hide();`

Comment: use class instead of id, id is be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID's have to be unique within HTML markup by specification. Assuming you have multiple elements with that exact same id, would lead to your experienced behavior (only the first element gets queried).

You should use *class names* instead of IDs and then call

```
$('.duracion').hide();   // will hide all nodes which own the classname "duracion"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked. I think it's to late for me to think correctly